# Does the COVID-19 Metro Manila curfew from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14 prevent travelers from going to the airport during the curfew hours?

Tags: airports, philippines, covid-19, manila

Does the [COVID-19 Metro Manila curfew from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14](https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1241807/curfew-hours-for-metro-manila-lockdown-malls-establishments-to-be-shuttered) (8pm to 5am) prevent travelers from going to the airport ([Ninoy Aquino International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninoy_Aquino_International_Airport), MNL) during the curfew hours?

---

Here are the unhelpful webpages I found so far:

https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1241807/curfew-hours-for-metro-manila-lockdown-malls-establishments-to-be-shuttered/amp:

> Going out to buy food is considered an essential purpose, Garcia said.
>
> Garcia said they are also mulling to recommend bars, establishments and other related entertainment shops to shut down during the 30-day quarantine which runs from March 15 to April 14.

https://www.gmanetwork.com/news/news/metro/729647/metro-manila-to-have-curfew-from-8-p-m-5-a-m-beginning-march-15/story/?amp:

> In press conference, MMDA General Manager Jojo Garcia announced on Saturday that all the mayors in Metro Manila agreed to issue a resolution to impose a curfew from 8 p.m. to 5 a.m., starting March 15 until April 14.
>
> Garcia, however, clarified that those covered by the curfew are non-essential activities such as “‘yung mga gumigimik lang, kung saan-saan nagpupunta, nakikibarkada, nakiki-party. Lahat ‘yan bawal na muna.”

MNL's airport phone number +63 02 877 1109 is useless (sounds like an automated ad? I don't get it.).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNnPXl
- https://redd.it/fifm2z

Comment: Call the airport or check the local papers. We are a world wide site, you are the best placed person to find out and likely the only one that wants to know.

Comment: @Willeke I checked local papers and I couldn't find the information yet. I don't think I am the only one that wants to know, since MNL airport isn't that small (45 million passengers per year).

Comment: This is as narrow in its use as the 'one airport' question I voted to close yesterday, but a bit less likely to change. I do not hammer this close but expect no answers and very few people honestly interested.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt Surely there’s an official local source that you can contact to find out?

Comment: @Traveller who? Police? Lawyer? Airport worker? Government officials? etc. Also, it's the weekend, so some might not be easy to reach.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt I’d start with whoever will be enforcing the curfew - the police or army? - and the airport. If you can’t find a local answer and you’re actually in Manila, it seems unlikely anyone on TSE will have better knowledge

Comment: @Traveller I'm assuming Filipinos know more about Manila than non-Filipinos. Being somewhere for a few days doesn't make someone an expert. Hence posting this question on this website.

Comment: Seriously, pick up the phone.

Comment: @Sneftel who do I call?

Comment: Police and airport seem like the most reasonable place to start.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt I don’t mean to sound unsympathetic but eg who would you call in this situation in your home country? And worse case scenario, if you can’t get a definitive answer, just go to the airport early, outside the curfew period.

Comment: @Traveller in my home country I could more easily find the official sources, since I know much better how the legal system and law enforcement work. I typically wouldn't try to call some random people on the phone because whatever they tell me isn't much trustworthy and wouldn't help my case if the information is incorrect and makes me miss a flight. But maybe things are different in Philippines. Also if each of us pick us the phone that's a time waste, let's instead make the information publicly and easily available. I think that's why stack exchange exists.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt I agree, however TSE usually prefers that people do some research first. It might help others to know which avenues you’ve tried up to now.

Comment: @Traveller sure, added

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt :-) I actually meant have you called the police and airport? Although, to me, it seems a pretty reasonable assumption that travel to the airport is prohibited during the curfew - it’s not ‘essential’ because there’s an alternative (travel there between 8am and 5pm, even if that means getting there earlier than you’d need to).

Comment: @Traveller I tried calling the airport, but I don't understand what's going on there, it sounds like the line is some automated announcement or ad. I haven't tried the cops yet, will do if I don't see any other options. But I'm far from sure if whoever I get on the line will be knowledgeable at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COVID-19 Metro Manila curfew from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14 (8pm to 5am) does not prevent travelers from going to the airport (Ninoy Aquino International Airport, MNL) during the curfew hours.

However, it has been announced on 2020-03-16 evening a total lockdown, which is supposed to 1) lead to the cancellation of all outbound international flights departing MNL starting in around 72 hours. 2) might reduce/remove all taxi traffic? I'm not sure, I've heard conflicting information from people who are supposed to know (e.g., MNL information counter). It's a mess, I've given up trying to understand (I think nobody does), and announcements, including presidential addresses, code-mix three languages (English, Filipino, and some dialect).