# Can I fly to New York from abroad, stay 4 days, and then leave abroad?

Tags: usa, covid-19, new-york-city, quarantine

I have a flight from South America to NY on Friday, I planned to stay there for 5 days or so and then I leave to Denmark. However, I just learned about the 14-days quarantine restrictions that are in place. Do you think I may not be allowed to fly out on the specified date?

Comment: from which country specifically are you coming?

Comment: Remember that in addition to quarantine, people who have recently visited some countries (such as Brazil) and are not exempt (US citizens and permanent residents, their spouses, etc.), are just not allowed at all into the US. Likewise, depending on your citizenship and status, you may have issues entering Denmark.

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to enter Denmark?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I have a job there and that’s part out the “worthy” purposes to enter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I fly to New York from abroad, stay 4 days, and then leave abroad?

Yes (obviously assuming you're allowed to enter the US and the subsequent destination country, which you may verify via [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm)).

https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/07/nys-covid-travel-advisory-faq_0.pdf ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924042403/https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/07/nys-covid-travel-advisory-faq_0.pdf)):

> Travelers from designated states may leave the state prior to the expiration of the 14-day quarantine period. However, to protect the public wherever you are, you should still maintain quarantine for the remainder of the 14-day period. Travelers are responsible for their own expenses during quarantine.

FYI same question for California:  [Am I allowed to go to the airport to catch a flight if I am supposed to self-quarantine in California, United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158793/1810)

Comment: If this is were actually the case, it would be a truly *horrible* policy.  For someone who is supposed to be in quarantine (and eg, not go into stores) to get into an aircraft cabin with others is just about the most grotesque violation of the point of being in quarantine imaginable.   Travelling somewhere in ones own automobile (or private light aircraft), staying less than the quarantine duration and then driving back home again in ones own automobile would work, but doing so in a shared vehicle cabin defeats the whole idea of requiring a quarantine!

Comment: @ChrisStratton the fact that the pandemic has affected 36 millions of people so far isn't a product of intelligence. E.g.  governmental authorities forced me to leave a covid-free country to come back to the US.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, and the pointer :) so I have to stay indoors all the time, except at the time of my outbound flight, right? Nonsense as @ChrisStratton said, but I guess it works. Thanks a lot